# Urn Question without Replacement

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm trying to understand how this works.

I have an urn with 6 white balls and 5 black balls. I then draw all 11 balls from the urn.

Now, let X be a random variable that takes the value y if the **first** white ball appears on the y-th draw.

How do I calculate the expected value of X?

I had thought that I would need to sum the value and probabilities, so:

$$ 1*\frac{6}{11}+2*\frac{6}{10}+3*\frac{6}{9}+\ldots+6*\frac{6}{6}$$

But I know my probabilities aren't right because they add up to too much. I had assumed the probability of drawing the first white ball on the first draw is 6/11 (6 white balls, 11 total), and the first white ball on the second draw is 6/10 (still 6 white balls, but now only 10 total) etc, but I'm clearly missing something....

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example. If I pick my first white ball on draw $y = 3$ then I took a black ball on attempts $1$ and $2$. What's the probability of this happening? The chance of drawing a black ball at attempt $1$ is $5/11$. Then, the chance that the second ball is also blacks is $4/10$. Finally, we must draw a white ball on attempt $3$, which occurs with probability $6/9$. To compute $P(X = 3)$ you must multiply these values. Do you see the general pattern in computing $P(X = y)$?

Once you have that, it's a matter of computing $E(X)$ via the usual formula $\sum y \cdot P(X = y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the you only have 2 white balls out of 11. The probability of selecting a white ball on the first draw is $\frac{2}{11}$.

What is the probability that you select the first white ball on the second draw? In words: it is the "intersection" of two events: event "1" is that you select a black ball on the first draw and event "2" is that you select a white ball on the second draw, given that you selected a black ball on the first draw. Denoting the event of a "first white ball on second draw" as $W_2$, we get:

$$\mathbb{P}(W_2)=\frac{9}{11}*\frac{2}{10}$$

So if you only had two white balls, the expected value of your variable would be:

$$\frac{2}{11}+\frac{9}{11}*\frac{2}{10}$$

Now you just need to adjust the numbers to 6 white balls.